# How to get datetime.now().isoformat() of future time?

Tags: python, datetime

I have

```
In [1]: from datetime import datetime

In [2]: datetime.now().isoformat()
Out[2]: '2019-11-05T14:55:58.267650'
```

and I want to get the `isoformat` of 10 seconds from now + change the format to yyyymmddThhmmss.

The format change can be done by:

```
In [6]: datetime.now().isoformat()
Out[6]: '2019-11-05T14:58:36.572646'

In [7]: datetime.now().isoformat().split('.')[0].replace('-', '').replace(':', '')
Out[7]: '20191105T145923'
```

But how can I add time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe use `datetime.timedelta()`, like this:

```
>>> import datetime

>>> now = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> now
datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 5, 10, 9, 16, 129672)
>>> new_date = now + datetime.timedelta(seconds=30)
>>> new_date
datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 5, 10, 9, 46, 129672)
```

Now format the new date as string:

```
>>> new_date.isoformat().split('.')[0].replace('-', '').replace(':', '')
'20191105T100946'
```

Or way cleaner using `.strftime()`:

```
>>> new_date.strftime("%Y%m%dT%H%M%S")
'20191105T100946'
```

Comment: Also, one can just use strftime to return desired format, instead of cutting and replacing the string - https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime + https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

Comment: instead of manipulating the string returned by `.isoformat()`, just use `.strftime("%Y%m%dT%H%M%S")`